# Schema management and migrations in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I used to utilize

```
Console/cake schema
```

in CakePHP 2.

Now I am on my way to CakePHP 3 and find out that `Console/cake schema` is gone.

So what is the recommended way to manage schema and migrations now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lorenzo from the CakePHP core has created the below plugin. <strike>It is currently under development and should be considered experimental.</strike>

<strike>CakePHP 3.0 database migrations plugin
https://github.com/cakephp/migrations</strike>

The Migrations Plugin is now part of the [CakePHP Core](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/migrations.html)

Comment: Thanks for the Plugin info, but I was looking for a way that the framework itself provides.

Comment: The Plugin URL you mentioned is 404, perhaps it has moved to https://github.com/cakephp/migrations

Comment: Yes, looks like it's gone. Starred it yesterday and saw your question. Not sure if Cake 3 will have a schema console. Sorry can't help you.

Comment: The repo was moved to github.com/cakephp/migrations as it will become the official plugin. It will support schema dumping very soon!

Comment: I'll accept Jose Lorenzo comment as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect current info.

Answer (score 0):

There are now 2 routes to generate migrations:

**Cake** (using bake)

```
bin/cake bake migration [migration_name]
```

**Phinx**

```
bin/cake migrations
```

Using the `Phinx` code above it will give you multiple options ie `create, migrate, rollback` - Create needs a migration name make sure to use `CamelCase`